# Dax for last sales date by ProductID in new custom column

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table with this information

| ProductID | Date sold |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2022 |
| 1 | 02/01/2022 |
| 2 | 01/01/2022 |
| 2 | 03/01/2022 |
| 2 | 04/01/2022 |

I now want to add a new column to the table in Power BI, and set a binary flag if that's the latest sales date for the ProductID. So, my expected output is this:

| ProductID | Date sold | Latest sales date for product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2022 | 0 |
| 1 | 02/01/2022 | 1 |
| 2 | 01/01/2022 | 0 |
| 2 | 03/01/2022 | 0 |
| 2 | 04/01/2022 | 1 |

How do I write the DAX for column *latest sales date for product* to get this output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the measure :

```
Latest sales date for product =
VAR _slct =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Date sold] )
RETURN
    IF (
        CALCULATE (
            LASTDATE ( 'Table'[Date sold] ),
            ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[ProductID ] )
        ) = _slct,
        1,
        0
    )
```

or if you want to add as a calculated column

```
    Latest sales date for product column = 
    
       

 IF (
        CALCULATE (
            LASTDATE ( 'Table'[Date sold] ),
            ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[ProductID ] )
        ) = 'Table'[Date sold],
        1,
        0
    )
```

Comment: Rookie mistake. Done :)

Answer (score 0):

With this measure

```
Latest sales date for product = MAX('Table'[Date sold])
```

you'll get

[image]

Comment: Yes, but the intention is to add a new column to an existing table, so I also need to see those dates that are not the last sales date for ProductID